How do I find the sum of integers in an array excluding repeating elements?
I almost succeeded with test cases except one. Here is the code in C++:
int main() {
    int summation=0;
    int size;
    cin>>size;
    int sum[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        cin >> sum[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        bool equal=true;

        for(int j = 0; j<i-1;j++){
            if(sum[i]==sum[j]){
                equal=false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(equal){
            summation+=sum[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<summation;
    return 0;
}

The prompt is to enter the size of the array followed by the integers.
test cases:
input: 5 1 2 3 2 1
expected output: 6 (worked)
input: 4 2 5 2 2
expected output: 7 (worked)
input: 7 -5 8 3 -1 -1 8 4
expected output: 9 (failed, the actual output is 8)

What did you do to try and find out the problem with the case that failed?

I tried moving around starting value of j in the loops a bit, I also tried to switch up the if statements before I used a boolean variable

Try this very simple case: 2 1 1. Use a debugger to trace the exe ution.

"I almost succeeded with test cases" - Ok, but int sum[size]; will not pass code review.

C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays. This is a C++ feature, which your compiler allows as a non-standard extension.

You should use std::array instead.

Your variable names are very confusing. sum doesn't contain sums, it contains the input numbers. equal is true when there isn't an equal number found.

Why is 9 the wrong answer for the last case? -5 + 8 + 3 + -1 + 4 == 9

I agree with @Barmar about the last test case - verified 9

I assume it is the expected value, but OPs code does not give it. If only they would give expected and received output...

@Yunnosch Oh, yes, of course :-) j<i-1 should be j<i.

@TedLyngmo Not that I saw the problem or the solution. I am just good at misunderstanding any written text in different ways until I find one which makes some kind of weird sense. Nice answer.

@Yunnosch That's a good trait! I wish I had more of that myself. Thanks!

@user25214124 This is all basically a two-line function.  Get to know your C++ algorithms and container classes.

for(int j = 0; j<i-1;j++){
//               ^^^ wrong

Example:
When i is 2, only sum[2] == sum[0] will be checked while sum[2] == sum[1] will not since 0 is the only value less than 1 (2 - 1). The effect is that it misses one -1 and adds it to summation.
The solution is to remove -1.

A different approach would be to use some of the features available in the standard library. The benefit by doing that is that you have less risk of making an algorithmic implementation error.

Containers, especially sets: A set (std::set/std::unordered_set) can only contain elements that are unique (a < b or b < a must be true for any two elements). Since you only want to count one of each value, a set may come in handy. If you try to put a value that already exists in a set, it will be rejected.
Iterators: Most containers, like the different sets, can be initialized using iterators.

You can create an iterator that reads ints directly from a stream, like std::cin, with std::input_iterator<int>(std::cin). The end iterator will in this case be a default constructed iterator of the same type. Using this kind of iterator pair would make it read ints from std::cin until it fails.
You however, only want to read size number of ints into the set, and to do that, you can put the input_iterators in a pair of std::counted_iterators (available from C++20).


Algorithms: For summing up the contents of a container (or an array), you can use std::accumulate or std::reduce.

Putting that together, the same program could look something like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>

int main() {
    int size;

    if (!(std::cin >> size) || size < 0) { // sanity check
        std::cerr << "Invalid size\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // initialize a set with up to `size` number of `int`s read from `std::cin`:
    std::set<int> values(
        // begin iterator:
        std::counted_iterator(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), size),
        // end iterator:
        std::counted_iterator<std::istream_iterator<int>>{}
    );

    // sum up the numbers in the set and print the result:
    std::cout << std::reduce(values.begin(), values.end(), 0) << '\n';
}

